# Can I start a stopwatch in one method and then stop the same stop watch in another method. And retrieve the time elasped?

Tags: c#

I need to start a stopwatch and then stop it in another class and then retrieve the amount of time that has passed. When I create a stopwatch object in `OnSignIn` method it does not see the creation of the object in the `OnSignOut` method. How should I fix this?

```
public void OnSignIn(int pin)
{
    if (this.pin == pin && this.SignIn == false)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
    }
    else if (this.pin != pin)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect pin or already logged in");
    }
}

public void OnSignOut (int pin)
{
    if (this.pin == pin && this.SignIn == true)
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();        
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can. Declare the stop watch at the class level.

Comment: sure, if you put the stopwatch object somewhere where both methods can get access to it

Comment: Should I put it in the constructor or class declaration?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do that, as long as the `Stopwatch` instance is available to both methods.

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Passing the shared instance as method parameter, or
2. Making the shared instance available as a field of the class that owns both methods

In your case the second approach works best: make `Stopwatch` a private field, then call `Start` in one method and `Stop` in the other method:

```
private readonly Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

public void OnSignIn(int pin) {
    if (this.pin == pin && !this.SignIn) {
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();
    } else if (this.pin != pin) {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect pin or already logged in");
    }
}

public void OnSignOut (int pin) {
    if (this.pin == pin && this.SignIn) {
        stopwatch.Stop();        
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Error!");
    }
}
```

**Note:** Comparing `bool` variables to `true` and `false` is unnecessary. You should write `if (x)` instead of writing `if (x == true)` ; write `if (!x)` for `if (x == false)`.

Also note that `if (this.pin != pin)` condition does not match the error message: since you do this additional check, the only reason an end-user would see the message is non-matching pin. When pin is matched but `this.SignIn` is already set to `true`, neither of the two branches in the conditional chain is going to be taken. Considering the text of the error message, you probably wanted to keep the `else` branch with no additional conditions.

Comment: It would be cool if you added a note regarding this... `this.pin != pin`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Right, his condition does not match his message. Thank you!

Comment: I never understood what people do that `if(x==false)` in c#. It might be relevant in other languages (I remember javascript as one of them), but not in c#, AFAIK...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Explicit comparisons to `true` and `false` become relevant in C# when `x` is `Nullable<bool>`. These comparisons are making a comeback in situations when nullability is added implicitly, e.g. when you access `myObject?.BoolProperty` and wish to allow `myObject` to be `null`.

Comment: Good point, though I find it hard to think of a situation where myObject is null should be handled different then when BoolProperty is false (I mean, it's easy to design a code like that, but I wouldn't think of doing that myself)

Comment: @ZoharPeled That is pretty common, at least for me, when working with nullables in Entity Framework

Comment: @dasblinkenlight By the way, I was referring more to the `this.pin` (field) vs `pin` (parameter) problem. It's a strong smell for me working with two different variables with the same name, but that might be just me

Comment: @camilo, it is just you.